# Navigating nested routes in NativeScript Angular

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-routing, nativescript-angular

In my NativeScript Angular Project this is my router module:

```
export const routes = [
 {path: "user", component: UserComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: "dashboard",
            component: DashboardComponent
        },
        {
            path: "notice",
            component: NoticeComponent
        },
        {
            path: "attendance",
            component: AttendanceComponent
        },
        {
            path: "subject",
            component: SubjectComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "discussion",
                    component: DiscussionComponent
                },
                {
                    path: "assignment",
                    component: AssignmentComponent,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: "assignment-report", component: AssignmentReportComponent
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

The `user.component.html` has a bottom bar with links for Dashboard, Notice and Attendance components which are displayed in a router outlet in UserComponent. A user clicks on a subject in `user/dashboard` route to go to a subject. The SubjectComponent again has two tabs for 'Discussion' and 'Assignment' displayed in a router outlet inside SubjectComponent.

**Problem:** When I am in SubjectComponent and click on any of the links in the bottom bar to navigate to Dashboard, Attendance or Notice, the app crashes and I get this error:

**An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Calling js method onPause failed
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference** .

It works fine if I just remove the `<page-router-outlet>` in SubjectComponent. I know I am somewhere messing up in nesting these routes but the error doesn't throw anything specific so I am unable to figure out.

**Playground Sample:** Open the playground sample and click on "Open Subject" button. When you are on the Subject Page, click on "Dashboard" button at the bottom. You will get the error.
Playground Link: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=qGvsVF&v=11

Adding some code snippets that might be relevant to this problem.

**user.component.html**

```
<GridLayout style="background-color: #ffffff;" rows="*, auto">
<StackLayout class="content-container" row="0">
    <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout class="bottom-bar" row="1">
    <StackLayout class="menu-container" horizontalAlignment="center" orientation="horizontal">
        <Image (tap)="openDashboard()" [ngStyle]="{'border-color': isHome?'#1d87c9' :'#ffffff'}" class="btn-home" [src]="menuImages[0]"></Image>
        <Image (tap)="openNotice()"  [ngClass]="{'btn-active': isNotice}" class="btn-icon" [src]="menuImages[1]"></Image>
        <Image (tap)="openAttendance()" [ngClass]="{'btn-active': isAttendance}" class="btn-icon" [src]="menuImages[2]"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**openDashboard() method in user.component.ts. openNotice() and openAttendance() are similar**

```
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {}

openDashboard(){
  this.routerExtensions.navigateByUrl('user/dashboard');
  this.menuImages = ["res://uni_full","res://notice_default","res://attendance_default"];
  this.isHome = true;
  this.isNotice = false;
  this.isAttendance = false;
}
```

**subject.component.html**

```
<StackLayout class="main">
<GridLayout rows="auto, *">
    <StackLayout row="0" class="subject-ribbon">
        <StackLayout class="tab-container" orientation="horizontal">
            <StackLayout (tap)="changeTab('discussion')" class="tab">
                <Label class="tab-label" text="&#xf27a;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Discussion"></Label>
                <Label class="tab-indicator"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout (tap)="changeTab('assignment')" class="tab">
                <Label class="tab-label" text="&#xf15c;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Assignment"></Label>
                <Label class="tab-indicator"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <ScrollView (scroll)="onScroll($event)" row="1">
        <StackLayout>
            <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

**subject.component.ts**

```
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {}

changeTab(tabName){
  this.tabMode = tabName;
  this.routerExtensions.navigateByUrl('user/subject/' + tabName);
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of nesting, can you setup a Playground sample?

Comment: I made a playground sample but I am unable to reproduce the error. Which means the problem apparently isn't with the routing. The only thing I know for certain is that in my original app, if I remove the <page-rouer-outlet> in subject component, it solves the problem.

Here is the playground sample: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=qGvsVF&v=7

Comment: If you hard code the image paths, not use property binding - do you still see the crash?

Comment: I replaced the image links with simple buttons. The crash is still there.

Comment: Without sample to reproduce the issue it's hard for me to tell. I would suggest you to look at android device logs see if that gives more information about the crash.

Comment: I am investigating. The issue is coming from assignment.component.html and discussion.component.html files. I am looking at their elements and for some adding "margin-bottom" in CSS is causing the crash, at other places, it is some other CSS property. Makes no sense whatsoever.

This is the crash message:

An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Calling js method onPause failed
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error. Open the playground sample and click on "Open Subject" button. When you are on the Subject Page, click on "Dashboard" button at the bottom. You will get the error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any. It (v7) works on my end with exact same steps.

Comment: v11 it is. Updated 4 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you had wrapped your frame (page-router-outlet) with a ScrollView. It's not a good practice for various reasons and the app seems to crash because of that. Moving the ScrollView within the page resolves the issue.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=qGvsVF&v=12)